# Is the pursuit of asymptotic variance for a novel estimator always required even if the estimator itself is complicated?

Tags: statistics, asymptotics, statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

I am working on an academic paper proposing a new estimator for a population mean. It works quite well in simulations across various superpopulation models (linear, quadratic, and strictly nonlinear).  However, it is very very involved, and I'm worried that a pursuit of the asymptotic variance/bias will not be fruitful.  Yet every paper I have included in my literature review has a section purely devoted to asymptotic results. Granted the proposed estimators there are not as complicated.

My question is this: is it frowned upon for me to focus on numerical approximations of the variance and bias instead? I am just honestly concerned of not being able to derive the asymptotics due to their complications.

Comment: Is the estimator so complicated you cannot apply the delta method to estimate variance?

Comment: @AaronHendrickson I may be mistaken, but to use the delta method, doesn't that require the CLT and the variance of the estimator?

Comment: Delta method needs the variance of the random variable used in the estimator and the derivative of the estimator to compute asymptotic variance.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson The proposed estimator uses medians and random variables in both the numerator and the denominator :/ Am just not sure how to find that variance without using some sort of approximation.